# Xen Kernel on Debian Squeeze making 1GB memory 'absent'

Tags: debian, memory, xen, kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fresh Debian Squeeze (6) Installation - Very High Ram Usage](https://serverfault.com/questions/249670/fresh-debian-squeeze-6-installation-very-high-ram-usage)

We have a Dell Poweredge R210 server with 8GB of installed RAM. This is a fresh install of Debian Squeeze, with pretty much only build-essentials and Xen 4.0.1 installed through aptitude. The kernel version is 2.6.32-5-xen-amd64.

1GB of our memory is "absent", and is not available and the output of `dmesg | grep Memory` is:

```
[    2.069861] Memory: 6842924k/8132468k available (3147k kernel code, 1058596k absent, 230948k reserved, 1908k data, 600k init)
```

Here is the output of `free -m`:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7195       1349       5846          0          3         28
-/+ buffers/cache:       1316       5878
Swap:         3813          0       3813
```

Whereas, if I use the original kernel (2.6.32-5-amd64), I have access to the full 8GB, despite 1GB still being absent - note the 9.5GB(!) apparently available:

```
[    0.000000] Memory: 8177956k/9437184k available (3079k kernel code, 1058596k absent, 200632k reserved, 1892k data, 592k init)
```

And `free -m`:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7995         91       7904          0          2         22
-/+ buffers/cache:         66       7929
Swap:         3813          0       3813
```

I am aware of the situation of absent memory being basically memory holes in the memory map https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=598290 - but why would a different kernel on the same hardware show such different behaviour?

So, my questions are:

1) Is this likely to be a kernel bug, and therefore should I report it?

2) Is there any hope for recovering the memory, or find out how / why the Xen kernel has taken it and fix it?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

1. No
2. No. Because Xen is allocating this memory for private use and also reserves s small fixed portion of every virtual address space.

Regards

Comment: But an eighth of the memory? Losing a full GB of RAM seems like some pretty heavy overhead for virtualization. I'm also pretty sure that our previous box took nothing like this much memory away - given, it was Ubuntu 8.04 and Xen 3.2.

Comment: Put xm list content here. with xentop you see all the memory  ?

Comment: `Domain-0                                     0  7195     8     r-----      5.8` we only have dom0 at the moment. And output from xentop: `Domain-0 -----r          5    0.2    6614132   78.9   no limit`